# Is there a command to sort but not remove usings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.  The code base has various using statements which sometimes appear unused due to #ifdefs in the code but are used in some situations.

Therefore, I do not want them removed but I do want them sorted.  I cannot find any commands that will sort but not remove them.

Does this command exist?

Comment: https://mattferderer.com/clean-up-sort-unused-dotnet-using-statements-in-visual-studio

Comment: You could also `#ifdef` the using statement.

Comment: @mjwills, thanks.  I swear I looked through that menu and it was not there before!

Comment: https://dailydotnettips.com/automatically-place-the-system-directives-first-when-sorting-usings-option-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I tried that but I just got discussions about sort and remove usings or references to menu options that I do not have! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Context menu option

Like Amit already posted, there is a possibility to do this via the context menu, but this is only available in VS2015. VS2017 changed it to "Remove ***and*** sort usings".

[image]

## Auto-formatting of code

Below `Tools > Options > Text Editor > *yourProgrammingLanguage* > Code Style > Formatting` there are 2 checkboxes below **Perform additional code cleanup during formatting** called **Remove unnecessary usings** and **Sort usings**. Here you can set them to only sort your usings if you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be one, as I have in *2015*, when I right click on the code
[image]

Do not have 2017 in machine, *though*, to verify.. :)

Comment: This feature has been edited in VS2017. You can only sort ***and*** remove using at the same time.